# showing a div when checkbox ticked

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way that I can make a div push the content below it when it is in the show state. What is happening at the moment, is that when i tick the checkbox, the textarea covers the submit button thus hiding it. Is there a way so the textarea can push the button down? I have placed my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JUcye/

and I think that if you try it you will see what I mean. Also, what is the way to control the speed that the div is displayed. Many thanks

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule to your stylesheet:

```
.contactmessage {
  float: left;
}
```

To make your div fade in over a time, change

```
$('input[name="messagetick"]').click(function() {
  $('.contactmessage').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

to

```
$('input[name="messagetick"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.contactmessage').fadeIn(250); // fade in over 250 miliseconds
  } else {
    $('.contactmessage').fadeOut(250); // fade out over 250 miliseconds
  }
});
```

Comment: fade does not work. i have updated fiddle with code. http://jsfiddle.net/JUcye/23/ thanks

Comment: Your fiddle is missing a the closing }); associated with the document ready function.

Answer (score 1):

Just set 'fb-input-right-conradio' height after showing textarea using jQuery.height(),

Comment: could you please expand on your answer? how do i use height with toggle? thanks